# sharelatex and xepersian, Arabic digits instead of hindi (Persian)

Tags: sharelatex, xepersian

I've uploaded my resume in my language (Persian) to my account in Sharelatex. I've also uploaded all required fonts to this project.

However, an annoying issue which I still couldn't resolve it is related to the numbers. All digits are in Hindi format when I compile using texlive in my laptop but once I compile it in sharelatex, they are changed to Arabic digits! to solve this issue, I installed a new virtual Persian keyboard and I could change them one by one, manually (very frustrating!).

However, I can't change 'page numbers' using this technique ! Page numbers are still in Arabic format ! would you please help me to know how can I change them to Hindi (Persian) digits.

Thank you

```
% !TeX document-id = {2945e35f-40c0-4ef0-9cad-f41eb4d0cccf}
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% Commands for running this example:
%    xelatex Amintoosi_CV
% End of Commands
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels=false}{hyperref} 
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{bidimoderncv}
% M.Amintoosi
% برای اجرا باید دنباله کارهای زیر را انجام دهید:
% xelatex Amintoosi_CV
% bibtex Amintoosi_CV
% xelatex Amintoosi_CV
% xelatex Amintoosi_CV

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{bibentry}
%\nobibliography*
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}%
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\cvtheme[blue]{bidiclassic}%casual} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{xepersian}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{fontspec}    %Added to use XB ZAR font in Sharelatex
%\settextfont[
%  Ligatures=TeX,
%  BoldFont=XB_ZARBD.TTF,
%  ItalicFont=XB_ZARIT.TTF,
%  BoldItalicFont=XB_ZARBDIT.TTF]{XB_ZAR.TTF}
%%%%%%%   OR   %%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{fontspec}    %Added to use XB ZAR font in Sharelatex
%\settextfont[
% Ligatures=TeX,
%  BoldFont=B_Nazanin_Bold.TTF,
%ItalicFont=B_.TTF,
%  BoldItalicFont=B_Nazanin_Black.TTF]{B_Nazanin_Regular.TTF}
%%%%%%%   OR   %%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}    %Added to use XB ZAR font in Sharelatex
\settextfont[
Ligatures=TeX,
BoldFont=XB_NiloofarBd.TTF,
ItalicFont=XB_NiloofarIt.TTF,
BoldItalicFont=XB_NiloofarBdIt.TTF]{XB_Niloofar.TTF}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB_ZAR.TTF}%{XB Niloofar}%{B Nazanin}%

%\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{TIMES.TTF}%{Linux Libertine}%
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=1.2]{IRANNASTALIQ.TTF}
\setdigitfont{nazli.ttf}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths} 
\firstname{}
\familyname{}
\resumename{رزومه}
\title{شرح حال}               
\address{}   
\mobile{۰۹۱۲380024445}
%\phone{}  
%\fax{شماره فکس}                          
\email{lopdp[11236@jdll.com]}
\extrainfo{}} 
\photo[64pt]{100320.jpg}                         
%\quote{نقل قول}  
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection{سیستم های عامل}
%\cvline{سیستم های عامل}{:}
%\cvline{سیستم های عامل:}{آشنايي کامل با ويندوز ، مکينتاش و توزيع هاي مختلف لينوکس (اعم از ردهت ، فدورا، سوزه، ابونتو وغيره)}
\begin{latin}
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{Windows}{Mac OS}
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{Linux (Redhat, Fedora, Suse, Ubuntu, etc)}{}
\end{latin}
\subsection{نرم افزارهای تخصصی}
%\cvline{برنامه های تخصصی}{:}
\begin{latin}
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{ANSYS HFSS}{CST Microwave Studio Suite }
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{Advanced Digital Systems (ADS)}{MATLAB }
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{AutoCAD}{AutoCAD }
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{SketchUp}{Solid Works }
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{Verilog HDL}{AWR-EDA }
    \begin{comment}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[$\bullet$] ~~\lr{High Frequency Structure Simulator (HFSS)}
    \item[$\bullet$] ~~\lr{CST Microwave Studio Suite}
    \item[$\bullet$] ~~\lr{Advanced Digital Systems (ADS)}
    \item[$\bullet$] ~~\lr{MATLAB, AutoCAD, SketchUp, Solid Works}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{comment}
\end{latin}

\subsection{نرم افزارهای کاربردی}
%\cvline{برنامه های کاربردی}{:}
\begin{comment}
\begin{latin}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\bullet$] ~~Microsoft Office (Word, Excel, Access, OneNote, Visio,         OutLook, PowerPoint)
\item[$\bullet$] ~~Adobe (Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign, Muse, After    Effect, Premier)
\item[$\bullet$] ~~\LaTeX, WinEdt, TeXMaker, Texstudio, Notepad++,Gedit, \TeX live, Latexila
\item[$\bullet$] ~~\XePersian, Farsi\TeX, Bib\TeX, MiK\TeX, Corel Draw and etc
\end{itemize}
\end{latin}
\end{comment}

\begin{latin}
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{Microsoft Office Products}{Adobe Products}
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{\LaTeX}{Web Design}
    \cvlistdoubleitem[\Neutral]{CorelDraw}{}
\end{latin}




\section{تألیفات}

\subsection{لیست مقالاتی که تاکنون به چاپ رسیده اند}
\def\refname{این لیست تنها شامل مقالاتی است که به \textbf{چاپ نهایی} رسیده اند و مقالاتی که در مرحله داوری هستند را\textbf{ شامل نمی شود}}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainyr}%{asa-fa}%
\setLTRbibitems
%\nobibliography{citations}
\bibliography{citations}
%\bibentry{majid2010utm}
\end{document}
```

***Update:***
I found where the problem is happening but I'm still looking for a solution! The issue relates to following part:

```
\settextfont[
Ligatures=TeX,
BoldFont=XB_NiloofarBd.TTF,
ItalicFont=XB_NiloofarIt.TTF,
BoldItalicFont=XB_NiloofarBdIt.TTF]{XB_Niloofar.TTF}
```

If I comment the above lines in my main code (in my laptop), it automatically uses the XB_Niloofar fonts which is installed in my laptop. But when I upload to Sharelatex or Overleaf, I need to upload them to root folder, too. Whatever the issue is, it is related to above 5 lines. How can I define the digit fonts in above lines ?
(I already used setdigitfonts but it didn't work)

Comment: Do you want the digits in Persian or Hindi? They're not the same thing. `1` in Hindi is `१`, in Persian (Farsi) it's `۱`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you please post a minimal working example (MWE)?
http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, I want them in Persian.

Comment: The code is added.

Comment: Please pay attention to the points mentioned in the above link. Your sample code should be copied-and-pasted and directly compiled. Now it has a bunch of dependencies and bugs. Please fix those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of your `Ligatures=TeX`. Here is a minimal example showing the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Yas}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

`\settextfont` uses `parsidigits` mapping and when you have `Ligatures=TeX`, you overwrite it with `tex-text` mapping. `parsidigits` does all necessary ligatures so `Ligatures=TeX` is not needed.

Comment: So appreciated for your help. I worked and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\setdigitfont` to set a Persian font for all the digits. Therefore all the numbers will be in Persian.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I already did but it didn't work. In fact, all the numbers are in Persian when I compile in my computer using Tex live 2015 (and Tex live 2016) and Texstudio but they are in English format when I compile in Sharelatex !